# Why I cannot get the UPS AD connection in powershell?

Tags: powershell, connection

I would like to get the AD connection from the UPS in powershell. But the object "ConnectionManager" is null. What I am missing?

If I go to:

Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage service applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Configure Synchronization Connections

There's only one connection and it's called "AD". (synchronising works btw)

I run this commando:

```
# Load the SharePoint PowerShell snapin if needed 
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
   Write-Host "Loading the SharePoint PowerShell snapin..."
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://nlsp004:44444");
$context = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPserviceContext]::GetContext($site);
#$upmanager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserprofileManager($context)
#$context = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($ups.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier]::Default)
#$ups = Get-spserviceapplication 8c421b58-ba4d-4f68-98c9-791b497f1194
$upcm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($context)

if($upcm -ne $null)
{
    "UserProfileConfigManager is not null"

    $xml = new-object xml
    $root = $xml.CreateElement("Connections")
    $xml.AppendChild($root) >> $null

    # Get AD Connections 
    #$ADConnections = $upcm.ConnectionManager | ? {$_.Type -eq "ActiveDirectory"}
    $ADConnection = ($upcm.ConnectionManager | select -First 1)

    if($ADConnection -ne $null)
    {
        $ADConnection.DisplayName
        $ADConnection.Server
        $ADConnection.UseSSL
        $ADConnection.Type
        $ADConnection.NamingContexts
    }
    else
    {
        "AdConnection is null"
    }
}
else
{
    "UserProfileConfigManager is null"
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm in my environment. Make sure to run it in a powershell window opened to run with an account like SPFarm to get enough permissions on the UPS

Comment: Thank you for your test. I will try it with another user. Did you test it on the front end server or app server?

Comment: THis was on my "all in one" dev environment